# How to format the date in xslt?

Tags: xslt

How can we format the date in xslt ?

Example:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="name of function(I/P, 'MMM dd, yyyy')"/>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 1.0, you might find the date formatting features in [EXSLT - Date and Times](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html) useful, in particular [format-date](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/index.html). If you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use the built-in function described in [Formatting Dates and Times](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date).

As en example of the latter, if you want to output a date on the format "Jan 01, 2020", you'd write

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="format-date($d, '[MNn,*-3] [D01], [Y0001]')"/>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide an example as well, since urls become outdated and is hard to find the right information. Like how would you display `MMM dd, yyyy` which the OP mentioned?

Comment: @m.spyratos Added example of invoking format-date.

Answer (score 4):

This will probably help: [ms:format-date Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099.aspx)

Using the example from the article you can format a date as follows:

> Date Unedited: 2000-02-16T15:56:00
>
> Date Edited: Feb 16, 2000

Comment: We had an error about "EnableScript".  We were using some VB code, inside the XSLT to reformat the date.  Since I couldn't apply the EnableScript flag on my XSLTs, they failed.

Using the ms:format-date function, I was able to remove that code, and still nicely format my dates.