# XSLT - format Date - remove milliseconds

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT to create XML file. A Date-time has milliseconds. I need to have the output XML without milliseconds.

Format needs to be `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

For example:

XML shows date as: `2012-12-341T09:26:53.132-0500`

But this needs to be: `2012-12-341T09:26:53`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2863422/62662

Comment: Or for XSLT 1.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt

Answer (score 2):

If all of the values are dateTime and have a `.`, you could use **[`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before)**:

```
substring-before('2012-12-341T09:26:53.132-0500', '.')
```

Of you could use **[`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring)** to select the first 20 characters:

```
substring('2012-12-341T09:26:53.132-0500', 0, 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT2, see this function: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-dateTime. This picture string should give you what you want:

```
format-dateTime($dateTime,'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')
```

Answer (score 0):

**This XPath expression produces the wanted result regardless whether the string contains a dot or a hyphen or both dot and hyphen, or none, and doesn't rely on the number of digits used for year, month, day**:

```
    substring-before(concat(substring-before(concat(substring-after(.,'T'),
                                                    '.'),
                                             '.'),
                           '-'),
                     '-')
```

**Here is a simple XSLT transformation that uses this XPath expression**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dt/text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'T')"/>
   <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-before(concat(substring-before(concat(substring-after(.,'T'),
                                                    '.'),
                                             '.'),
                           '-'),
                     '-')
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this test XML document:**

```
<t>
 <dt>2012-12-341T09:26:53.132-0500</dt>
 <dt>2012-12-355T09:34:56</dt>
 <dt>2012-12-355T09:34:56-0500</dt>
 <dt>2012-12-13T9:34:5-0500</dt>
 <dt>2012-12-344T09:12:34.378-0500</dt>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <dt>2012-12-341T09:26:53</dt>
   <dt>2012-12-355T09:34:56</dt>
   <dt>2012-12-355T09:34:56</dt>
   <dt>2012-12-13T9:34:5</dt>
   <dt>2012-12-344T09:12:34</dt>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper application of **[sentinels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)**.