# Altering the date format in XSLT

Tags: datetime, xslt-1.0

I have a XSLT sheet that returns and formats a date as below:

```
<result column="name" isNull="false">2017-08-08</result>
      <result column="display" isNull="false">08-08-2017</result>
```

Ideally, I would like the information to be displayed as 'Tuesday 08 July'. Is this possible?

The current XSLT is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ArrayOfdateItem">
      <date>
         <name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
     </name>
     <display>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(node(),9,2),'-',substring(node(),6,2),'-',substring(node(),1,4))" />
      </display>
    </date>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
    <soap:Body>
        <GetBulkyWasteDatesFromDate
            xmlns="http://">
            <GetBulkyWasteDatesFromDateInput>
                <UPRN>{customerDetails/uprn}</UPRN>
                <threshold>16:00:00</threshold>
                <startDate>{startDate}</startDate>
                <includeToday>false</includeToday>
            <noOfAvailableDates>3</noOfAvailableDates>
        </GetBulkyWasteDatesFromDateInput>
    </GetBulkyWasteDatesFromDate>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Use XSLT2 and its date-time formatting functions (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format the date in xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863422/how-to-format-the-date-in-xslt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a date in XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt)

Comment: `2017-08-08` is in August, not in July.

Answer (score 1):

To do this purely in XSLT 1.0 is a bit verbose. Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<dates>
    <date>2017-07-23</date>
    <date>2017-07-24</date>
    <date>2017-07-25</date>
    <date>2017-07-26</date>
    <date>2017-07-27</date>
    <date>2017-07-28</date>
    <date>2017-07-29</date>
</dates>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="date">
    <date>
        <xsl:call-template name="format-date">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </date>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="format-date">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date,1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="JDN" select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />  
    <xsl:variable name="day-of-week" select="($JDN + 1) mod 7" />    

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week=0">Sunday </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week=1">Monday </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week=2">Tuesday </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week=3">Wednesday </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week=4">Thursday </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week=5">Friday </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week=6">Saturday </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($day, '00')" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$month=1"> January</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=2"> February</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=3"> March</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=4"> April</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=5"> May</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=6"> June</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=7"> July</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=8"> August</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=9"> September</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=10"> October</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=11"> November</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$month=12"> December</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dates>
  <date>Sunday 23 July</date>
  <date>Monday 24 July</date>
  <date>Tuesday 25 July</date>
  <date>Wednesday 26 July</date>
  <date>Thursday 27 July</date>
  <date>Friday 28 July</date>
  <date>Saturday 29 July</date>
</dates>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this will provide me with the answer I need. It is currently not providing any formatted results when I test it, could this be something to do with the XML returning 3 values each time that means the code has to be amended?

Comment: I don't see your XML, so I have no way of knowing.

Comment: I have included the XML in the original post minus the live xmlns. Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid at this point I have no clue what this is about. I don't see any dates in the input XML (unless `{startDate}`  is supposed to represent a date - but then I don't know in what format it is). And I don't see that it is "returning 3 values each time" anywhere. Most importantly, there is no `ArrayOfdateItem` which your XSLT supposedly handles.

Comment: {startDate} is a a system token where the user select the earliest date they require, the integration then returns the next 3 available dates via webservice.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you're talking about.