# XSL 1.0: Change text value into date

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xsl file:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Header/Details/Date" />
```

And the xml file has:

```
<Header>
    <Details>
        <Date>20180716</Date>
    </Details>
</Header>
```

And I want to get this date and to convert it into: 16.07.2018
I could do that with substring, but the problem is that I don't know how to insert this value into a variable...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863422/how-to-format-the-date-in-xslt

Comment: @PankajJaju That's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do it with substring, then should be no problem putting the result in a variable...

```
<xsl:variable name="date">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(Header/Details/Date, 7, 2)" />
  <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(Header/Details/Date, 5, 2)" />
  <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(Header/Details/Date, 1, 4)" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$date" />
```

Or maybe this...

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="concat(substring(Header/Details/Date, 7, 2), '.', substring(Header/Details/Date, 5, 2), '.', substring(Header/Details/Date, 1, 4))" />
<xsl:value-of select="$date" />
```