# Date and time formatting in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0, date-formatting

I'm struggling to format a value into a DateTime format in XSLT 1.0

My Input XML has two tags as shown below.

```
<dateamdaddr>
20220426
</dateamdaddr>

<timeamdaddr>
130404
</timeamdaddr>
```

My output should be something like

`Tue, 26 Apr 2022 13:04:04 GMT`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format the date in xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863422/how-to-format-the-date-in-xslt)

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any of the date and dateTime functions that 2.0 and above have. The easiest way in 1.0 is to use extension functions. Is there a reason why you can't use a later version of XSLT?

Comment: Actually, except for the day of the week, this is a fairly trivial exercise even in XSLT 1.0. Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Thanks all. This issue is now resolved.